# Number Turns to String over Http Request from Angular Client to NestJS Server

Tags: angular, http, get, httprequest

Number Turns to String over Http Request from Angular Client to NestJS Server:

I pass `firstIndex: number` through the params of a GET http request from my Angular client to my NestJS server. Everywhere I define it as a number. In the params of my service function `firstIndex: number`. When grabbing it from the server side `@Query('firstIndex') firstIndex: number` But when I try to use it, I run into problems. When I log the `typeof firstIndex` it comes out as a string. I have to convert it to a number using `const firstInd = Number(firstIndex)`.

I'm assuming this is just something to do with the nature of http requests themselves, but I'm intrigued to know the speicific reason.

Comment: What is the method you use to get the query parameters in your server?

Comment: `@Get()                                                                                  getRows(@Query('firstIndex') firstIndex: number, @Query('limit') limit: number, @Query('sorts') sorts: string)` Does this answer your question?

Comment: Are all the other parameters the expected type?

Comment: No, limit also comes out as a string when it is supposed to be a number. Same scenario. But yes sorts does come as a stirng.

Comment: It seems like all query parameters are of type String. Since I have never dabbled in NestJS, I would highly advise you to read the documentation on the code that you have written and see if there is some implicit conversion there behind the scenes.

Comment: I tried, but thanks! I'll keep looking. It's really not a big deal to have to convert them to a number on the server side. Was mostly just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I was getting started with NestJS and routes.

Then, while going through the documentation and some open source NestJS API projects, I found multiple ways to tackle this issue.

1. You can utilize `ValidationPipe` to automatically transform the payload to your desired type.

There are two ways to do it.

The first one is to apply the `ValidationPipe` at your controller method level.

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) // <--- Add this line
getRows(
  @Query('firstIndex') firstIndex: number,
  @Query('limit') limit: number,
  @Query('sorts') sorts: string
){
  console.log(typeof firstIndex === 'number'); // true
  console.log(typeof limit === 'number'); // true
  console.log(typeof sorts === 'string'); // true
}
```

The other way to apply the `ValidationPipe` behavior at global level.

This is how you would do it in your NestJS App instantiate file:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```

*(`ValidationPipe` and `@UsePipes()` decorator are imported from the `@nestjs/common` package)*

You can read more about this in [NestJS Transform payload objects doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects).

2. The second way is to explicit convert the type of the value.

This is how you can get it done:

```
@Get()
getRows(
  @Query('firstIndex', ParseIntPipe) firstIndex: number, // <-- Added ParseIntPipe
  @Query('limit', ParseIntPipe) limit: number, // <-- Added ParseIntPipe
  @Query('sorts') sorts: string
){
  console.log(typeof firstIndex === 'number'); // true
  console.log(typeof limit === 'number'); // true
  console.log(typeof sorts === 'string'); // true
}
```

(The `ParseIntPipe` is imported from the `@nestjs/common` package)

As you can see, here, I have passed another parameter which is a `Pipe` in the `@Query` decorator. It will parse the value as an integer.

You can read more about [NestJS Transform Explicit conversion doc here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#explicit-conversion).

External Links:

- [NestJS Validation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)